# Detect url hash value to trigger click event

Tags: jquery, hash, click

Trying to check to see if the current url has a hash value #video-value, if it does run the same click action that is used for  tag link actions that live on the same page.

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
function showVideo() {
    var $anchor = jQuery(this),
        url = $anchor.data("url"),
        title = $anchor.data("title");
    jQuery("#help-video-iframe").css("visibility", "hidden");
    jQuery("#help-video-iframe").addClass("loading");
    jQuery("#help-video-iframe").load(function() {
        jQuery("#help-video-iframe").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
    jQuery("#help-video-div-label").empty().append(title);
    jQuery("#help-video-iframe").attr("src", url);
}

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#help-videos-list a").click(showVideo);
    jQuery("#help-videos-list .caption").equalizeHeights();
});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for the existence of any hash value:

```
if ( window.location.hash ) {
    //do something
}
```

To manually set the hash, you can do this:

```
window.location.hash = 'some-hash';
```

Comment: Sorry i wasn't super clear, i just want to know if it has ANY hash value not that explicit one. How do i get the hash value to be the same as if i had clicked the <a> on the page. Also allowing for standard onlick on page of the few <a>'s i have.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking. See my updated answer for the general concepts.

Comment: I want to use the same function of showVideo(). for both on page clicks and also if there is a hash on the end of a url. But right now i need to pass the hash value to the showVideo() function to target that item vs the jquery(this) which is taken from the on click action.